# Leaving a High-Deductible Health Plan (HDHP) during the year: can one still fully contribute to one's HSA?

Tags: united-states, health-insurance, hsa, contribution

Bob has a High-Deductible Health Plan (HDHP) and wants to maximize his contributions to his Health Savings Account (HSA). At some point during the year, Bob changes his health insurance from an HDHP to a non-HDHP. How much can Bob contribute to his HSA during this year?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously assuming Bob is not covered in the month of December, thereby negating the last month rule there's a monthly prorating.  The annual maximum is $3,450, there are 12 months, $3,450 divided by 12 is $287.50 times however many full months Bob is covered by an HSA qualified HDHP.